# Can I forward VPN traffic to another vpn clients?

Tags: linux, iptables, vpn, openvpn, route

I've run OpenVPN server on SERVER-1.

**Client1**(10.8.0.2) and **Client2**(10.8.0.3) have a connected to **OVPN SERVER-1** (pubIP:87.x.x.x | privIP:10.8.0.1)

And I've other **SERVER-2** with connected 3 VPN clients **SERVER_CLIENT1**(tun0), **SERVER_CLIENT2**(tun1) and **SERVER_CLIENT3**(tun2) to other VPN servers (this is not my server, other vpn providers)

How I can route for **Client1**(10.8.0.2) from **SERVER-1 via SERVER-2 -> SERVER_CLIENT1** (tun0) ?

It is Real ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is real, but you need to explain more.

In common you have to:

1. Ensure SERVER_CLIENT* have routes to Client* through tunnel
2. Ensure Client* have routes to SERVER_CLIENT* through tunnel

If you are the administrator of SERVER-1 and SERVER-2 - there should be no problem. Then:

3. Ensure SERVER-2 have route to Client* via SERVER-1 and vice versa.

Here everything should be fine.

If this can not be achieved - you have to build NAT on your SERVER-*.

Comment: Yes I'm administrator SERVER-1 and SERVER-2 but SERVER-1 on Amazon and SERVER-2 on hetzner cloud.
I can build NAT through Openvpn ?

Comment: If SERVER-1 and SERVER-2 are connected through public internet your best shot would be using some tunnel between them - IPSEC or VPN. There is no way you can connect clients from not connected private networks.

Comment: You will probably need to enable client-to-client within opnvpn